# How do I find the current virtual terminal

Tags: linux, shell, console

I am working around a problem in Ubuntu 10.04 where after resume, the mouse cursor disappears.

This can be "fixed" by running `chvt 1; chvt 7` in a script in /etc/pm/sleep.d, such that those commands run on thaw and resume.

However, the X console is not always vt #7, so `chvt 7` is wrong in those cases.

What I would like to do is find out the current vt in the fix-up script and make sure I change back to that vt.

How can I find the current vt? (tty(1) just reports "not a tty")

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check if 'fgconsole' does what you need. Seems to work for me (eg, returns 7 and I'm currently in X)

Answer (score 0):

A method which does not require root privileges:

```
$ cat /sys/class/tty/tty0/active
tty7
```